# Как получить путь для записи файла?

Tags: android, android-assets

Есть класс, записывающий файл. На сайте Developers нашёл способ записывать в файл через `File`:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Но не понимаю, откуда взять context (файл не `extends Activity`, просто `Java`-файл).

А вообще, мне нужно указать папку в папке `assets` (она уже есть). Если не трудно, покажите, пожалуйста, готовую строчку / кусок кода, который пишет в `assets`.

UPD. Есть второй вариант записи файла, только он требует экземпляр `Context`:

```
    String filename = "myfile";
    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = Context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`Context.openFileOutput` — не работает, поскольку `openFileOutput` не `static`. Есть ли возможность получить экземпляр `Context`?

Comment: В assets нельзя писать, только читать

Comment: А куда можно? Как грамотно составить путь для записи внутренних файлов программы?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context - верхушка иерархии объектов для доступа к ресурсам, к файловой системе, вызов активности и т.д... Т.е. Activity наследник Context - если вы осуществляете вызов:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

в классе `Activity` - можете напрямую вызвать:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), filename);
```

более подробно на русском языкеможно прочитать здесь: [Context](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php)

Comment: Спасибо, с контекстом я уже сам кое-как разобрался. Не подскажете, как прописать путь к assets?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов `getAssets()`

Comment: Уже выяснили, что в assets файлы не пишутся.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов тогда предлагаю хранить файл в директории самого приложения - `getFilesDir()`

Comment: Тогда помогите, пожалуйста, со строчкой. Как написать? Интересует второй вариант.

Comment: `context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + IMAGE_PATH + "/" + fileName;` где IMAGE_PATH - константа имени папки для файла (внутри директории приложения), fileName - имя файла с расширением (многие забывают). Также стоит учесть что директория приложения находится в data/data/ - без рута в эту директорию вход заказан, да и с рутом не всегда она коректно просматривается - что не мешает работать с файлами из кода)))

Comment: Вот я пользуюсь этой строчкой: `fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("a111.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` Но куда здесь вписать путь?

Comment: Дело в том, что Bitmap.compress требует именно FileOutputStream.

Comment: `String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + IMAGE_PATH + "/" + fileName;
fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/user/0/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch/files/charts/asdfg.png contains a path separator` я так понял, вместо filePath всё-таки должен быть fileName

Comment: `String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + IMAGE_PATH + "/" + fileName;
File file = new File(filePath);
file.mkdir();
 fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
FileOutputStream принимает File в не путь - та же ошибка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator